# Is there a way to allow the play function of an audio element to run in chrome headless browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, google-chrome-headless

When running `new Audio.play()` in a unittest the following error is thrown:

```
'play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first'
```

I've tried running ChromeHeadless with this flag `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required` but the error remains when used in combination with the --no-sandbox flag which is necessary to run chromeheadless as a root user (See https://crbug.com/638180). Anyone has a workaround to run this inside tests as a root user (thus with the ---no-sandbox attribute)?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an user gesture on your page from HeadlessChrome.
Assuming a CRI setup, something like

```js
await client.Input.dispatchMouseEvent({ x, y, button: 'left', clickCount: 1, type: "mousePressed" });
await client.Input.dispatchMouseEvent({ x, y, button: 'left', clickCount: 1, type: "mouseReleased" });
```

would be enough to be granted the authorization to play audio.
Just like in prod., your script would need to listen for that event before trying to play the audio.

---

If you don't want to setup the click listeners etc. in your tests, and assuming you don't actually need the sound of the `<audio>` element, but rather just see how other things react while it's playing, you could also use a muted `<video>` element instead of an `<audio>` element. Indeed, `<video>` elements can also play audio media just well, and will expose all of the same methods and events as `<audio>` elements (and more) since the [`HTMLAudioElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#htmlaudioelement) interface doesn't add more to the [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#htmlmediaelement) interface that [`HTMLVideoElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#htmlvideoelement) extends.

So for your test, you can write a function that will return a new `<video muted>` element and use that instead of your `Audio()` constructor.

```js
function createAutoPlayableAudio(src = "") {
  return Object.assign(
    document.createElement("video"),
    {
      muted: true,
      src
    }
  );
}
const src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/transcoded/d/dc/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_(Beatles_song_-_sample).ogg/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_(Beatles_song_-_sample).ogg.mp3";
const audio = createAutoPlayableAudio(src);
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", (evt) => {
  document.querySelector(".log").textContent = audio.currentTime;
});
audio.play()
  .then(() => console.log("playing"))
  .catch(() => console.log("failed to play"));
```

```html
<pre class=log></pre>
```